# Assigning value of a variable to another variable in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have this snippet in my script:

`set line [gets stdin]`

`set $line1 $line`

Is it wrong?
I basically want to copy the value of variable `line` to `line1`. It gives me error:

```
can't read "line1": no such variable
while executing
"set $line1 $line"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tcl, prepending `$` to a variable replaces that variable with its value. Therefore the correct syntax is:

```
set line1 $line
```

This is almost the same semantics as `*` in C: prepending `*` to a pointer in C dereferences it to its value.

Comment: The use for `set $line1 $line` is where the `line1` variable contains the name of another variable. It's usually a sign of unmaintainable code; there are much clearer approaches (arrays and/or `upvar` being the most common ones).